# ¿Cómo crear un lector de RSS en Phonegap?

Tags: phonegap, rss

¿Cómo puedo crear un lector de *RSS* en *Phonegap* que lea el artículo de forma inteligente? Es decir, que lo lea sin salir de la aplicación y sin *WebView*.

Busqué pero no encontré la manera de hacerlo.

Comment: @AlejandoMatos algo similar a curl de php?

Comment: Realmente no, en realidad en **Phonegap** solo se programa con los lenguajes HTML, CSS, JavaScript y hay un apartado de xml, lo que quiero es crear un lector de rss con HTML o JavaScript porque con CSS no se puede ya que es  el lenguaje de diseño.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si lo que buscas es orientacion para incorporar un lector rss a tu app
[aqui](https://docs.monaca.io/en/sampleapp/samples/sample_rss_reader/) hay un ejemplo.

Si quieres crear una aplicacion con un lector rss tambien te sirve el link pero tendrias que empezar por
[crear un app en cordova](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/es/latest/guide/cli/index.html#crear-la-aplicaci%C3%B3n)

Recuerda que phonegap no es mas que html/javascript/css. tienes que pensar el diseño como cualquier webapp.

Comment: si eso lo se y Muchas Gracias!!!